# Comparing a value to multiple values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am having an issue with this code:

```
words = []
counter = 0
wordcount = 0
intraWord = 1
loop = 0
ConsonantCluster3 = ["sch" "scr", "shr", "sph", "spl", "spr", "squ", "str", "thr"]
while(loop == 0):
    sentence = input('Enter a sentence in english: ')
    sentence.lower()
    words = sentence.split()
    for x in range(0,intraWord):
        if(words[counter][:3] in ConsonantCluster3):
            print("True")
            input()
        else:
            print("False")
            input()
```

My goal is if, for example, the user inputs "screen" the program would spit out True, but instead it is spitting out False. I am using Python 3.

Comment: You're missing a comma between `"sch"` and `"scr"`.  Adjacent string literals are concatenated. Try printing out `ConsonantCluster3`, you will see `"schscr"` in the first position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
ConsonantCluster3 = {"sch", "scr", "shr", "sph", "spl", "spr", "squ", "str", "thr"}

sentence = input('Enter a sentence in english: ')
words = sentence.lower().split()

for x in words:
    if x[:3] in ConsonantCluster3:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

**Explanation**

- Many of your variables and a loop are not necessary.
- Your list is missing `,` after the first element.
- You can loop through a list simply via `for x in lst`.
- `str.lower()` is not in-place. Assign to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of list comprehension to combine the conditions to make the code simpler:

```
ConsonantCluster3 = {"sch", "scr", "shr", "sph", "spl", "spr", "squ", "str", "thr"}

sentence = input('Enter a sentence in english: ')
words = sentence.lower().split()

if len([x for x in words if x[:3] in ConsonantCluster3]) > 0:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```